# Uploading a file meanwhile you keep interacting with the website

Tags: javascript, php

I got a web app working with a PHP MVC on the server side and javascript on the client side.
What I'm trying to do, is upload a file and meanwhile, do other tasks in the website until the response comes from the server.

Here bellow I post the code I'm using right now:

```
function xhr(url, data, callback) {
   'use strict';

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
         callback('The content has been uploaded');
      }
   };
   request.open('POST', url);
   request.send(data);
}
```

The main problem here is when I request a new page, I don't know how to get the response.

Any help with this?.

Comment: look into nodejs and websockets.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

Comment: Can you give me an example of "meanwhile, do other tasks in the website"

Comment: I was looking for the youtube processs (upload a video meanwhile you're watching other videos). Patrick Murphy
I assume this is an assync process, but was trying to avoid nodejs/websocket due to this is a small app. 
I will test these other options.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is not a single page application, once the user clicks on a link and gets redirected the upload progress might get canceled if it's not complete. If the upload to the server is complete at the time the user goes to another page, it will succeed but you will loose the reference to the object that has initialized the `xhr` object, thus, you won't be able to get the response. Now, What I would do, is take a look at the `shared webworkers` API.

You could delegate the file upload to the worker (which is a separate thread).

```
//define a worker
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
}, false);
worker.postMessage('Hello World'); // Send data to our worker.
```

And your worker.js file:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        self.postMessage(data);
    }
};
request.open('POST', url);
request.send(data);
```